# Presto throws "Document does not contain key clusterTime" for every MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, presto, mongodb-atlas, trino

I'm using PrestoSQL (334/338) to read data from a *hosted* MongoDB (Atlas).

Presto connects successfully to the Mongo catalog but every query (for various schemes, tables, collections) fails with the error

```bash
Query 20200719_060423_00001_xcbmw failed: org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: Document does not contain key clusterTime
```

(None of my collections defines **clusterTime** field)

Following is my mongodb catalog file:

```bash
connector.name=mongodb
mongodb.seeds=XXX-shard-00-00-6owtm.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,XXX-shard-00-01-6owtm.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,XXX-shard-00-02-6owtm.gcp.mongodb.net:27017
mongodb.credentials=xxx:xxx@reader
mongodb.ssl.enabled=true
mongodb.write-concern=MAJORITY
mongodb.required-replica-set=XXX-shard-0
```

full stack trace:

```bash
Query 20200719_073435_00001_c5cee failed: org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: Document does not contain key clusterTime
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: Document does not contain key clusterTime
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2051)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3951)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4964)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.mongodb.MongoSession.getTable(MongoSession.java:171)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.mongodb.MongoMetadata.getTableHandle(MongoMetadata.java:80)
    at io.prestosql.plugin.mongodb.MongoMetadata.getTableHandle(MongoMetadata.java:55)
    at io.prestosql.metadata.MetadataManager.getTableHandle(MetadataManager.java:320)
    at ...
Caused by: org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: Document does not contain key clusterTime
    at org.bson.BsonDocument.throwIfKeyAbsent(BsonDocument.java:859)
    at org.bson.BsonDocument.getTimestamp(BsonDocument.java:257)
    at com.mongodb.connection.ClusterClock.greaterOf(ClusterClock.java:40)
    at com.mongodb.connection.ClusterClock.advance(ClusterClock.java:31)
    at com.mongodb.connection.ClusterClockAdvancingSessionContext.advanceClusterTime(ClusterClockAdvancingSessionContext.java:71)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.updateSessionContext(InternalStreamConnection.java:509)
    at ...
```

Comment: Could you share the full stacktrace using CLI --debug option or webui? 
I would recommend to join the community Slack so that we can talk interactively. https://prestosql.io/slack.html

Comment: @ebyhr I have added stack trace to the question, and this is my original post from the slack channel- https://prestosql.slack.com/archives/CGB0QHWSW/p1594748101137100

Comment: Confirmed the upstream doesn’t cause the issue. Please wait the next version 339. It will released in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed on PrestoSQL **339**